# TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, controller, angularjs-controller

Im try to use Oboe.Js and Angular.Js together

Here is my sample code which is working correctly..

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ng-oboe'])
 .config(function (oboeProvider) {
             /* If we were so inclined, we could change the oboe defaults here - headers, etc. */
             // oboeProvider.defaults = {};
     })
 .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, oboe) {
                $scope.test = "Yo.";
                $scope.items = [];

                oboe.get('http://localhost:4243/containers/f78257b77b21/stats')
                        .start(function (data, etc) {
                        })
                        .node('!', function (value) {   
                        })
                        .done(function (value) {
                                console.log("It works! ", value.read);
                                $scope.items.push(value);
                        })
                        .fail(function (error) {
                                console.log("Error: ", error);
                        });
        });
```

But when I try to use these code with my actual project controller. I'm getting this error. I can't figure out Why I'm getting this.

> Error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

module.js

```
angular.module('RDash', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router', 'ngCookies','ng-oboe'])
  .config(function (oboeProvider) {
      /* If we were so inclined, we could change the oboe defaults here - headers, etc. */
      // oboeProvider.defaults = {};
  });
```

stats-ctrl.js

```
  angular
  .module('RDash')
  .controller('StatsCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', StatsCtrl]);

  function StatsCtrl($scope, $stateParams, oboe) {

    var id = $stateParams.id;

    $scope.myData = [];

    $scope.items = [];

    console.log('http://localhost:4243/containers/' + id + '/stats');

  oboe.get('http://localhost:4243/containers/' + id + '/stats')
        .start(function (data, etc) {
            console.log("Dude! We're goin'!", data, etc);
        })
        .node('!', function (value) {

        })
        .done(function (value) {
            console.log("It works! ", value.read);
        })
        .fail(function (error) {
            console.log("Error: ", error);
        });
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you are injecting oboe in your controller setup.

Comment: @MatthewGreen sorry, I'm forget to add module.js file.  I already injected 'ng-oboe' my module.js file. Do I need to injecting in controller file again ?

Comment: I'm not talking about your module, I'm talking about the controller. You have `$scope, $stateParams` but no `oboe`.

Comment: Oh okay! Thanks! It escaped me! @MatthewGreen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your controller function you have `obe` factory has no value(undefined), because it haven't been injected inside DI array.

```
angular
  .module('RDash')
  .controller('StatsCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'obe', StatsCtrl]); //<-inject obe here
      function StatsCtrl($scope, $stateParams, oboe) {
```

Comment: yea, Im so sorry about that. It's my fault :(

Comment: @ErolGuzoğlu Glad to help you..Thanks :)